# "Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a" following \IfFileExists

Tags: errors

I tried to use a switch `\IfFileExists` to define a command differently, but I get the illegal parameter error. I am running LaTeX from TeX Live 2021.
A minimal example is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\IfFileExists{filename}
{\newcommand{\ABC}[1]{{\begin{color}{Red}{#1}\end{color}}}}
{\newcommand{\ABC}[1]{{\begin{color}{Blue}{#1}\end{color}}}}

\begin{document}
\ABC{Why?}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you need `##`not  ``#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\IfFileExists` doesn't work like “usual” conditionals: it stores the true and false branches in macros, and uses them later.  This requires you to double every `#` in there:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\IfFileExists{filename} %                 VV
{\newcommand{\ABC}[1]{{\begin{color}{Red}{##1}\end{color}}}}
{\newcommand{\ABC}[1]{{\begin{color}{Blue}{##1}\end{color}}}}

\begin{document}
\ABC{Why?}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. This was not my real question, unfortunately -- I posted the easier example hoping that it help with the bigger one. Since I can't figure it out, here is the actual true branch I want (which I got online to enable me to input a table as a file and use \midrule etc.):

```
\IfFileExists{filename}{\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \expandableinput #1
  { \use:c { @@input } { \file_full_name:n {#1} } }
\AddToHook{env/tabular/begin}
  { \cs_set_eq:NN \input \expandableinput }
\AddToHook{env/tabular*/begin}
  { \cs_set_eq:NN \input \expandableinput }
\ExplSyntaxOff}{}
```

Comment: To be clear, I did try doubling # to ## in the \ExplSyntax construction, it does not work.
My goal is to apply this construction when I compile the file on my computer, as opposed to a coauthor running an older latex implementation. (Until he bothers to update..) That's why I used the \IfFileExists.

Comment: @nicolae That's a very different problem.  You are using `\ExplSyntaxOn` inside the argument of `\IfFileExists`, but commands like `\ExplSyntaxOn` don't work (as you'd expect) inside arguments.  You were a victim of the [XY problem](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2449/134574). I would suggest you ask a new question with the actual problem you want to solve

Answer (score 2):

You're best served with a different approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\ABCdo}[2]{\leavevmode{\color{#1}#2}}

\IfFileExists{filename}
  {\newcommand{\ABC}{\ABCdo{Red}}}
  {\newcommand{\ABC}{\ABCdo{Blue}}}

\begin{document}
\ABC{Why?}
\end{document}
```

Output with `filename` (which does not exist):

[image]

Output with `latex.ltx` (which exists):

[image]

There is no `color` environment and, anyway, the text should not be braced.